# [Jenkin][MacServer] Jenkin not accessible remotely

Tags: macos, jenkins, server, remote-access, screensharing

I setup Jenkin on Mac-server and able to do build locally for both iOS and Android source code.

I am facing issue while accessing the Jenkin's on remote machine(Same Mac server) from home. Mac-Server is ping-able from Home but Jenkin's is not accessible.

**We found out that to able to access the Jenkin's we always need to enable screen sharing. Login to screen sharing is not needed just connecting(IP Address of remote mac server) enables Jenkin's to be accessible.**

### System Details below

1. Mac server OS version : macOS Big Sur 11.2.3
2. Jenkins version: 2.319.2
3. Jenkins installed via Homebrew

Any support/guidance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Amit, check if the MAC server is not in sleep mode. You can check this under System Preferences->Energy Saver option. Select the first checkbox if it is not selected "Prevent computer from sleeping automatically when the display is off".

This should resolve the connectivity issue with MAC server without the need to use screen sharing.

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to turn off the firewall of Mac

Comment: Yes, MAC Server Firewall is turned off